# elasticdump doesn't import json file

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used `elasticdump --input=2016-1-1-2016-7-31-2.json --output=http://localhost:9200/my_index`

and got:

```
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:51:41 GMT | starting dump
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:51:42 GMT | got 1 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:51:42 GMT | sent 1 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:51:42 GMT | got 0 objects from source file (offset: 1)
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:51:42 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:51:42 GMT | dump complete
```

but `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices` doesn't show anything.

What's wrong here?

btw: I plan to use elasticdump to import a folder of json files.

My json file looks like:

```
{"response":
 {
   "status": "OK",
   "results":[
              {"id": "1"},
              {"id": "2"}
             ] 
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the first few lines of your json file ?

Comment: @Val just added an example

Comment: Your JSON file must have the same format as the one shown in  https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/blob/master/test/seeds.json , basically the same as you would get if the input was ES and output was your file

Comment: @val that helps! thanks